# Remove HTML tags from pyspark dataframe columns

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am loading data from json file to pyspark dataframe and in one of the text columns I have HTML tags
Ex. < span>text &lt < p>text&gt text&nbsptext\ntext < /span>

Is there a way to remove HTML tags from this column? I know it can be done using pandas but i don't want to convert all my dataframes to pyspark then convert it back as it will take lot of time.